# Desktop is cropped

Tags: 16.04, display, desktop-environments

My desktop looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it is cropped - I only see the bottom part of the top toolbar, and the right side of the left toolbar (when there are open windows near the bottom or right of the screen, I see similar cropping effects in these sides, too).

The current screen resolution is 1920x1080.  I can change it to 1360x768, but then I have much less room on the screen.

Output of `lspci | grep VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
```

Interface: `HDMI1`

Comment: What is your gpu?

Comment: @MarkKirby What is a gpu and how do I find it?

Comment: What type of Graphics Card? Nvidia? Intel? AMD? Run `lspci | grep VGA` to find it.

Comment: Here is what I get:

     00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)

Comment: How do you connect HDMI? VGA? Laptop?

Comment: I have a laptop. Its DisplayPort output is connected to a DisplayPort-HDMI adapter, which is connected to the HDMI input of the screen.

Comment: Set it to your external display and run this `xrandr|grep conn` and tell me what the `connected` device is,some thing like HDMI-1 or VGA-1 but for your display port.

Comment: HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm

Comment: Ok now run `xrandr --output HDMI1 --transform 1.05,0,-35,0,1.05,-19,0,0,1` it should adjust the edges of the screen, might be better or worse IDK but you need to adjust the numbers at the end `1.05,0,-35,0,1.05,-19,0,0,1` until it fits the screen. I can't give you an exact command, I don't have access to the computer but play around until you are satisfied and then post back here, I will tell you how to make it permanent.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi have you tried changing clock or clock phase on the HDMI monitor you mention ? Some monitors have setting for that

Comment: @Serg I do not see such option in the Display Settings

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi  Those settings are typically located on the monitor itself, not related to Ubuntu Settings in any way. There's supposed to be a  Menu button on your monitor, so try to explore what options it has

Answer (score 0):

Temporary workaround- put this in a script and run it from terminal:
    #!/bin/bash

```
# $ chmod 755 ScreenFix.sh

# $ ./ScreenFix.sh

# hborder is side margins vborder is top and bottom

#sudo shutdown -r +1

xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set underscan on &&

xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set "underscan hborder" 35 --set  "underscan     vborder" 17

#echo sudo shutdown
```

Comment: I get this error message: X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  41